# Hexadecimal to Integer in Java

Tags: java, integer, hex

I am trying to convert a String hexadecimal to an integer. The string hexadecimal was calculated from a hash function (sha-1). I get this error : java.lang.NumberFormatException. I guess it doesn't like the String representation of the hexadecimal. How can I achieve that. Here is my code :

```
public Integer calculateHash(String uuid) {

    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        digest.update(uuid.getBytes());
        byte[] output = digest.digest();

        String hex = hexToString(output);
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);
        return i;           

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("SHA1 not implemented in this system");
    }

    return null;
}   

private String hexToString(byte[] output) {
    char hexDigit[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
            'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int j = 0; j < output.length; j++) {
        buf.append(hexDigit[(output[j] >> 4) & 0x0f]);
        buf.append(hexDigit[output[j] & 0x0f]);
    }
    return buf.toString();

}
```

For example, when I pass this string : **_DTOWsHJbEeC6VuzWPawcLA**, his hash his : **0xC934E5D372B2AB6D0A50B9F0341A00ED029BDC15**

But i get : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "**0xC934E5D372B2AB6D0A50B9F0341A00ED029BDC15**"

I really need to do this. I have a collection of elements identified by their UUID which are string. I will have to store those elements but my restrictions is to use an integer as their id. It is why I calculate the hash of the parameter given and then I convert to an int. Maybe I am doing this wrong but can someone gives me an advice to achieve that correctly!!

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: first of all number is too big for regular integer.

Comment: As Andrey says, it won't fit in a regular integer.  If you're happy to change to java.math.BigInteger, you can just `return new BigInteger(1, digest.digest())`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Why do you not use the java functionality for that:

If your numbers are small (smaller than yours) you could use:  `Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)` to convert a Hex - String into an integer.

```
  String hex = "ff"
  int value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
```

For big numbers like yours, use `public BigInteger(String val, int radix)`

```
  BigInteger value = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
```

@See JavaDoc:

- [Integer.parseInt(String value, int radix)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)
- [BigInteger(String value, int radix](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29))

Comment: I really don't get this answer, isn't that what he's already trying in `Integer i = Integer.parseInt(hex,16);`?

Comment: Additionally get rid of the `0x` part... I don't know that this is allowed.. and if you can guarantee that it will always be `0xABC982..`, then you can always just remove the first 2 chars

Comment: I think you mean to instantiate a new BigInteger in your third line of code?  It also ought to be more efficient to construct directly from the byte array rather than the hexadecimal string representation.

Comment: @eggyal: You are right, it is new BigInteger - I have corrected it

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public static long Hextonumber(String hexval)
    {
        hexval="0x"+hexval;
//      String decimal="0x00000bb9";
        Long number = Long.decode(hexval);
//.......       System.out.println("String [" + hexval + "] = " + number);
        return number;
        //3001
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally find answers to my question based on all of your comments. Thanks, I tried this :

```
public Integer calculateHash(String uuid) {

    try {
        //....
        String hex = hexToString(output);
        //Integer i = Integer.valueOf(hex, 16).intValue();
        //Instead of using Integer, I used BigInteger and I returned the int value.
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
        return bi.intValue();`
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("SHA1 not implemented in this system");
    }
    //....
}
```

This solution is not optimal but I can continue with my project. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 produces a 160-bit message (20 bytes), too large to be stored in an `int` or `long` value.  As Ralph suggests, you could use BigInteger.

To get a (less-secure) int hash, you could return the hash code of the returned byte array.

Alternatively, if you don't really need SHA at all, you could just use the UUID's String hash code.

Comment: I tried to use the UUID's String hash code but I get also IllegalArgumentException. This is why I drop UUID; By the way, I don't even know how they generate their UUID, it is not my project

Comment: By "UUID's String hash code" I mean `uuid.hashCode()` (which uses the function `String.hashCode()`).  I can't see that giving an IAE?

Comment: Yeah, i know. I just tried this method. But the problem is when I try String id = UUID.fromString(uuid) i get an IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31804061/3343174
it's converting perfectly any hexadecimal number (presented as a string) to a decimal number

Answer (score -2):

That's because the `byte[] output` is well, and array of bytes, you may think on it as an array of bytes representing each one an integer, but when you add them all into a single string you get something that is NOT an integer, that's why. You may either have it as an array of integers or try to create an instance of [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).

Comment: Is it possible to convert from BigInteger to Integer?

Comment: Only if the value of BigInteger is not larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE which in this case it will be. See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue()

Comment: This answer is basically meaningless. An array of bytes is simply a multiple-precision number. Doesn't answer the question.