# NumberFormatException to many hex chars

Tags: java, android

I am receiving an exception when I insert to many hex characters into a string that is being converted to an integer value.

Code:

```
//variables used in this problem
int INT_MAX = 2147483647;
int INT_MIN = -2147483648;
int currentBase = 16;
string displayValue;

switch(currentBase) {
    case 16:
        if((Integer.valueOf(displayValue + "F", currentBase) >= INT_MIN) && (Integer.valueOf(displayValue + "F", currentBase) <= INT_MAX))
        {
            displayValue += "F";
        }
        break;
}
```

The error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6944): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "FFFFFFFF"
E/AndroidRuntime(6944):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(6944):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:378)
E/AndroidRuntime(6944):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
E/AndroidRuntime(6944):     at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:510)
E/AndroidRuntime(6944):     at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.send_f(MainActivity.java:968)
```

I need this string to have a value no larger than size int (32 bits).  Any suggestions?

Comment: Make your number smaller? What are you asking?

Comment: the number is user input, i am trying to use this value in a calculator that supports doublewords (32 bits).

Comment: As you seem to already be aware, Java `int` values range from -2147483648 to 2147483647. The hex value 0xFFFFFFFF is 4294967295, which is outside this range.

Comment: how could i take 0xFFFFFFFF and use it to represent its negative value (-1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greg Hewgill's comment is correct.  It looks like you're trying to have the bits be automatically interpreted.  Probably the simplest thing to do is something like

```
 Long.valueOf(displayValue + "F", currentBase).intValue();
```

to get the bits, and then truncate them to int.  Of course, now it's your responsibility to ensure that the argument to `Long.valueOf` fits in 32 bits.

Comment: thank you! i got everything working and now have a much better understanding of how these conversions work!

Answer (score 1):

FFFFFFFF is too big, max int value is 0x7FFFFFFF the workaround is

```
int i = (int)Long.parseLong(hexStr, 16);
```

Comment: thanks, i understand 0x7FFFFFFFF is the max int value. how would i take 0xFFFFFFFF and get the int value of -1?

Comment: (int)Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFFF", 16) gives -1, try

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    // try your calculation here
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // assign the variable the max/min value instead
    // or whatever behavior you want
}
```

This code will provide default behaviors for numbers that are out of range.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are using a wrong method for hex string to int conversion , if my this understand is wrong let me know

I am quoting a duplicate post

```
    String hex = "ff"

// small values
    int value = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);  

// big values
    BigInteger value = new BigInteger(hex, 16);
```

[refer for the duplicate post i quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5886656/1897935)

[API refrence for the  method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)