# I want to convert a binary string to corresponding hex string.But when the input binary string long then NumberFormatException is shown.How to fix it?

Tags: java, string, hex

My code is here.Actually I want to convert a binary string such as "0100001110111111" into corresponding hex format.The code is working fine for small input strings but for long input string NumberFormatException is shown and it is not working.

```
    public class Test 
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        {
           System.out.println("The value of " + args[i] + " is " +
           Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(args[i], 2)));
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: [How can I convert a string into hex in Java] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946597/how-can-i-convert-a-string-into-hex-in-java

Comment: [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

```
String s = "0100001110111111010000111011111101000011101111110100001110111111";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(s, 2);
System.out.println(bi.toString(16)); // prints: 43bf43bf43bf43bf
```

Comment: @Charleemagnee Then please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, so others can see your question has been answered to your satisfaction.