# Smartly Decoding Hex Input (e.g 0x32, 0x3, 32 etc...)

Tags: java, string, hex

I seem to be going around in circles with this one... There are many methods to achieve this and I could use a few `if` statements like I've done int he example below, but I want a smarter method.

## Problem

The user is asked to input a value in hex, the program grabs this string and will now want to convert it into an integer, bearing in mind this is a hex value. The input could be for example:

`0x00`
`0xf`
`ff`
`2`

## My Attempt

```
String hexString = response.getResult(); //grabs the user input

int hexInt = Integer.decode(hexString); //Doesn't work if the user doesn't add "0x" at the start

String regex = "\\s*\\b0x\\b\\s*";
String hexInt = hexString.replaceAll(regex, ""); //Doesn't like 0x for some reason

Int hexInt = Integer.valueOf(hexString,16); //Doesn't like 0x
```

Any ideas on how to do this smartly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886619/hexadecimal-to-integer-in-java#5886656

Comment: "I could use a few if statements like I've done int he example below" - your sample code doesn't include any `if` statements.

Comment: Sorry it didn't, I meant to. I have the answer I need now though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just remove `0x` if the string starts with it? There's no need to use a regular expression for this - just a combination of `startsWith` and `substring` is simpler to understand (IMO):

```
String hexString = response.getResult();
if (hexString.startsWith("0x")) {
    hexString = hexString.substring(2);
}
int value = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

Comment: Maybe a bit shorter: `int value = Integer.parseInt(hexString.replace("0x", ""), 16);` or better with the if?

Comment: @ifLoop: That would accept "50x5" whereas I'd expect that to be an error.

Comment: Didn't think of that. Convinced me!