# How to convert string to hex bytes in Java

Tags: java, android, string, hex

I want to split each of two chars in string and convert it to hex byte array representation,
i am just lost how to do this.

in string a= hex a which is 10 in decimal
in string b= hex b which is 11 in decimal

```
String toConvert = "abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc";
byte[] output = new byte[12];





                          Input
 ab    bb   bb    bb  bb   bb   bb   bb   bb   bb   bb   bc
                          output
[-85, -69, -69, -69, -69, -69, -69, -69, -69, -69, -69, -68]
```

Comment: no i want a byte array ass output not string and its string to hex not hex to string.

Comment: You reserved 12 bytes for a 24 charackter string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886619/hexadecimal-to-integer-in-java

Comment: example (ab)  a is msb and b is lsb i want to combine them and make a 16bit no than convert it to hex

Comment: `in string a= hex a which is 10 in decimal in string b= hex b which is 11 in decimal` You mean in `String toConvert`? What a terrible example! Better `String toConvert = "0344A7DF";`. And you will not convert to hex but decode from hex representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takes the first character in a group of two, multiplies its hex value by `16` (it's in the `161` place). That result is added to the second character's hex value.

```
String toConvert = "abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc";
byte[] output = new byte[toConvert.length() / 2];

for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    output[i] |= Character.digit(toConvert.charAt(i * 2), 16) * 16;
    output[i] |= Character.digit(toConvert.charAt(i * 2 + 1), 16);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Common Codec's [Hex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html) class does exactly what you need:

```
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex("abbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbc".toCharArray());
```

If you can't/won't use third parties, you can always "borrow" their implementation (slightly simplified - I omitted correctness checks for simplicity):

```
public static byte[] decodeHex(final char[] data) {

  final int len = data.length;

  // Handle empty string - omitted for clarity's sake

  final byte[] out = new byte[len >> 1];

  // two characters form the hex value.
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++) {
      int f =  Character.digit(data[j], 16) << 4;
      j++;
      f = f | Character.digit(data[j], 16);
      j++;
      out[i] = (byte) (f & 0xFF);
  }

  return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    output[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(toConvert.substring(i*2, i*2+2), 16);
}
```

Comment: Primitives don't have methods. Maybe you meant `Integer.valueOf`?

Comment: No, I meant what I wrote :)
Integer is not a primitive.
Just try running it, you'll see.

Comment: @Dima I'd run it, if I could (does not compile, because of what has been stated above).

Comment: sure it does, c'mon. Try it.

Comment: Oops, I see what you meant. Fixed the answer. Thanks

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. It is always better to explain the what, why, and how.

Comment: Hmmm. I think, sometimes seeing the code is clearer than any human-language explanation. 
Can you suggest what in particular about this snipped deserves to be explained in more detail?