# processing hex string to color

Tags: java, colors, hex, processing

I'm reading hex colors from a JSON file, but need to get them as an int so I can create a color.

```
int col=Integer.parseInt("FF0000",16);
```

returns `16711680`

```
int c = unhex("FF0000");
```

returns `16711680`

how do I do this?

Comment: *how do I do this?* **do what?**

Comment: convert a hex string to a usable color or an int of that color's value

Comment: Use the available constructors? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)

Comment: It's done well apparently what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was simply recreated the color like this:

```
int c = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("color"), 16);
c = color(red(c), green(c), blue(c));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reinvent the wheel, you could parse out the string into RGB hex values "FF", "00", and "00", convert the hex values to integers (255, 0, and 0 respectively) corresponding to int values from 0-255, and then create a Color object with those RGB values.

Personally though, I'd just use:

```
Color red = Color.decode("#FF0000"); //That's definitely red
```

Comment: Please note the [tag:processing] tag. Processing is its own language, and you should **not** use Java's AWT `Color` type inside Processing. Recommended reading: [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java)

Comment: Given the **java** tag it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: I didn't say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating two things:

**Thing one:** Hex values like `#FF0000` represent integer values.

**Thing two:** Internally, Processing represents color values as integers.

The integers in the first concept are not the same thing as the integers in the second concept.

In fact, hex color values are a special case in Processing of the Processing editor doing some magic for you. I don't know of a way to go directly from a string value to a hex color value.

Instead, you should parse the String value into its individual components, convert them to integers, and then use the three-argument `color()` function to create a color.

See this question for more info: [Hexadecimal to Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886619/hexadecimal-to-integer-in-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following -

```
Color c = Color.parseColor("#c0c0c0");
```

Answer (score 0):

`int c = -16777216 + unhex("FF0000");`