# How to convert the RFID tag UID to a single integer value

Tags: arduino-esp8266

```
if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()){
 if ( mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()){
       Serial.print("Tag UID:");
       for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
              Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
              Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
        }
```

Above is my code for RFID tag reading i wanna to convert the UID of tag into a single integer value

Comment: so what the problem with the above code ?

Comment: it gives a HEX value which i want to convert to an integer value

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886619/hexadecimal-to-integer-in-java ?