# Android Studio ColorPicker output convert to byte arrays

Tags: java, android

i have a ColorPicker in my Android App and i want to control LEDs, so i need the colors seperatly in byte[1]= Red; byte[2]= Green; byte[3]= Blue to send the colors. But the Color Picker provides the Colors by a method (get.color()) in this format: 0xFF00FF00. Ho can i divide this output to three different byte arrays?
Thank you!

Comment: And FF is wich color? Why giving such a confusing example? And that integer is four bytes. And not four byte arrays.

Comment: You can also send those the bytes of that integer. The receiver can then pick the right byte if needed.

Comment: Further get.color() will return an integer. Not a hexadecimal notation of that integer value.

Answer (score 0):

To get the int value of a hex-string use [hex-integer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29)

for example this will print out -16711936:

```
int val = Long.decode("0xff00ff00").intValue();
System.out.println(val);
```

also this might help:

[Hexadecimal to Integer in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886619/hexadecimal-to-integer-in-java)